# python3＋SQlite　でPDFデータをINSERTするにはどうすればよいか

Tags: python, python3, database, sqlite

こんにちは。python3を使ってSQliteに接続し、PDFや画像データなどを登録したいと思っています（リンクを登録するのではなくデータを直接登録したいと考えています）。

blob型というものがあるというところまでは分かるのですが、
・画像データ→blob型への変換はどうしたらよいか
・pythonでそれを実現するにはどうしたらよいか
が分からず困っています。

自分なりに検索してみたのですがやり方が分かりません。
教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite3はBLOBを標準で[サポート](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect)しています。

Web上を検索するとpython2.xで`buffer(blob)`を使ってバイナリを渡すサンプルコードが見つかりますが、python3ではバイナリデータを直接insertできます。
selectもバイナリデータをそのまま返してくれますので、バイナリを書き込めば画像を復元できます。

下記のサンプルコードの読み込み画像ファイルパスをpdfに書き換えるだけでpdfの読み書きも可能です。

```
import sqlite3
from contextlib import closing

rf = 'C:\\test\\read.jpg'  #読み込み画像ファイルパス
wf = 'C:\\test\\write.jpg' #書き込み画像ファイルパス

with closing(sqlite3.connect('blob_test.db')) as db:
  #適当にテーブル作成
  cursor = db.cursor()
  try:
    cursor.execute('create table img_table (img blob);')
  except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    cursor.execute('delete from img_table')
  #バイナリ読み込み
  with open(rf, 'rb') as f:
    blob = f.read()
  #レコード追加してコミット
  db.execute('insert into img_table values(?)', [blob])
  db.commit()
  #せれくと
  for row in cursor.execute('select img from img_table limit 1'):
    blob = row[0]
  #バイナリ出力
  with open(wf, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(blob)
  #後始末
  db.execute('drop table img_table')
```

Comment: ありがとうございました！　助かりました。